# Fulltext index search slow on order by desc in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, indexing

I have 80 million records in my database (InnoDB) and i have use fulltext search index for searching record now it's working fine but i have add condition order by desc for  one of field after adding this condition my query working 70 to 80% slow compare to old query so how can i increase my query speed. i have use laravel for my app. my code look like this

```
$food_data = Nutrition::whereRaw("MATCH(brand_with_name) AGAINST (? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)", [$item])
    ->with('guNutrition', 'esNutrition')
    ->limit($per_page)
    ->offset($off_set)
    ->orderBy('nutritions.updated_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

i have try https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730 but this solution increase up to 5 to 7% speed compare to the current situation.
Currently my query take 20 to 45 second (depend on search)

Comment: Perhaps its time to use a tool like https://www.algolia.com/

Comment: @Kyslik Thanks for reply but i want to solution with existing fulltext index without using any paid tool

Comment: You could use select in select. it should speed up things. `select * from (select * from nutrition where MATCH AGAINST) order by nutritions.updated_at desc limit X,Y` - it will sort only results, not all records. Also if Nutrition has columns which you dont need, dont select them (dont use `select *`, but `select name, id ...` - in the inner select, if you will be using select in select).

Comment: @Autista_z You are right but i'm not able to do this because i want to search latest updated record first then other. after searching record shorting order is not necessary

Comment: as per you say shorting record after getting filter data but i don't want to this

Comment: But Mysql dont work in that order. if you have one select. It will first sort 80 milion records by updated_at and then it will select records, which match your brand name, then it will make ofset and limit. if you will have 2 select, it will first search  records, which match your brand name, and then orders this records (e.g. 10 milion) by updated_at and then ofset+limit. but result will be the same, only order by will have to sort less records and it will be faster.

Comment: No result will be not same because i have select limit record and if i not set limit in inner query then it take too much time and my problem is there